# Loopback android sdk REST api with filter

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, loopbackjs, asynchttpclient

As I am trying to make use of loopback to develop an application where users could filter data using one to four criteria, depending on their need, I tried to search through the web to see if there is any solution. It seems that this feature has not been built by [loopback](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android/issues) community. Then, I could think of two possible ideas but not sure if they would work so I hope to see if someone could provide me some insight into it.

1. Custom method. I have very basic understanding of custom method on loopback but it seems we could create new rest api from these methods. Thus, I wonder if I could create a custom method accepting four nullable parameter to filter the data.
2. Asynchttpclient or other connector library like retrofit. I think this one should work but may take more time to develop. I tried to make use of retrofit to build a simple application with CRUD operations and I found that it could accept dynamic filter so I think I can filter data using this method, in particular, retrofit, to filter data with my user token.

Could anyone tell me if these two methods are viable?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the loopback custom remote method is concerned, yes it is viable.

Once you get into the actual code to build the remote method, I would suggest having it accept a single parameter filter *object* which could hold one or more optional filter parameters, instead of a remote method spec that would require nulls. Just depends on what you favor more—not needing to update the method signature for new filters, or being explicit with the param list. Either way you can add validation.